# Swift JSON Encode Issue

Tags: json, swift, encode

I am trying to decode some JSON in swift, but I keep getting an error, which I am assuming is because my struct is not written correctly. Any ideas? I am calling this API https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/

Here is the json decode call:

```
func fetchPokemonImages() {
        
        for var pokemons in self.Pokemons {
            
            let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            if let url = URL(string: pokemons.url) {
              let request = URLRequest(url: url)
              let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let pokemonImage = try? JSONDecoder().decode(PokemonImageList.self, from: data!) else {
                  print(error)
                  return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.PokemonsImage.append(contentsOf: pokemonImage.sprites)
                    self.PokemonTableView.reloadData()             }
              }
                dataTask.resume()
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are my structs:

```
struct PokemonImage: Codable {
    let back_default: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case backDefault = "back_default"
    }

    init(backDefault: String) {
        self.backDefault = backDefault
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let postsContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        backDefault = try postsContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .backDefault)
    }
}

struct PokemonImageList: Codable {
    
    let sprites: [PokemonImage]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sprites
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the error message?

Comment: Why are you still doing `try?` instead of `try`? Are you aware that the error you are printing when the decoding fails is the parameter to the closure so it has nothing to do with the decoding.

Answer (score 1):

from the API your share `sprites` is an object, not an array

```
"sprites": {
        "back_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/1.png",
        "back_female": null,
        "back_shiny": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/shiny/1.png",
        "back_shiny_female": null,
        "front_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png",
        "front_female": null,
        "front_shiny": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/1.png",
        "front_shiny_female": null,
        "other": {
            "dream_world": {
                "front_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/1.svg",
                "front_female": null
            },
            "official-artwork": {
                "front_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/1.png"
            }
        }
```

so `sprites` in PokemonImageList should be an object, not an array

```
struct PokemonImageList: Codable {
    
    let sprites: PokemonImage

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sprites
    }
}
```

Comment: I think  this might be the issue, thanks. I'm having another error now though related to appending the codeable object `pokemonImage` to the array `PokemonsImage`. (Instance method 'append(contentsOf:)' requires that 'PokemonImage' conform to 'Sequence')

Comment: use append(_ newElement: Element) to append 1 object, append(contentsOf:) is used to append an array